# Sending arrays to PHP server using Node Request?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, however I have an array of data, and I need to send this to a PHP API.

In Postman, I can make this work by going to the Body and selecting `form-data`.  Under my keys, I then make 1 key for every array entry

```
names[0] = "tom"
names[1] = "harry"
```

Is there a way to do this using request, or do I have to pass my array through a function and pass it to formData like `formData: { 'names[0]': 'tom', 'names[1]': 'harry' } }`

What I am currently doing is

```
    const response = await request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        formData: {names: ["tom", "harry"]}
    });
```

Comment: Try stringifying the data.

Comment: Replace `names` with `'names[]'`

Comment: The server is expecting the variable `name` to contain the values. You are sending the variable `names` - which is the correct parameter name?

Comment: @daddygames plural typo.  Have fixed my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

what format of data server accept?
if you want to send as FormData use this code...

if your postman code works, you can generate code for request by postman, below the send button on the right side is link `code` where you can chose `nodejs` then `request` and postman will generate for you request code...

```
const data = new FormData();
names.forEach((name)=> data.append("names[]", name));
const response = await request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        formData: data
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I am using Node, not in the browser.  As such FormData doesn't work.  There is a node package called form-data, but I believe Request already utilises this when you pass data via the formData value.